# PyQt5/Python3 reference qss file

Tags: import, path, pyqt5, python-3.8, qtstylesheets

I have a PyQt5 (5.15.6) application running in Python 3 and want to reference my qss file as such

qss_file = QtCore.QFile("my_app_qss.qss")

However, I have multiple apps that use the same qss file so depending on where I run the app from I need an absolute import rather than a relative import. I would also like to compile any of those apps with pyinstaller and deploy them to another machine. How can I reference this qss file?

example folder structure

```
main
| - resources/my_app_qss.qss
| - apps/
|--------project1/app1.py
| -------project2/
|-----------------subfolder/app2.py
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to do that in order to always maintain a single qss file without risking to have multiple versions that don't match (otherwise, considering that qss files usually are not *that* big, I'd suggest you to forget about the problem and just copy qss files for each appilcation). The point is: you cannot (nor should) use an absolute path, unless you are absolutely sure that all apps are installed and executed with the same, **hardcoded** root path, and that that path will *never* change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I did not understand that

```
qss_file = QtCore.QFile("my_app_qss.qss")
```

Is not a path to a file. It is referencing a file that gets built by pyrcc4 from the .qrc source